# My web scrapping program is pulling information that seemingly doesn't exist on the page it's crawling and I can't figure out why

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = "https://www.aia.org/firm-directory?filter%5Bcountry%5D=UNITED%20STATES&filter%5Bstate%5D=FL&page%5Bnumber%5D="

firmName = []

for i in range(1):
    page = requests.get(url + str(24))
    print(url + str(24))
    soup = bs(page.content, "html.parser")
    info = soup.find('table', class_='data-table')

    for b in soup.find('tbody').find_all('b'):
        firmName.append(b.get_text())
    print("Frim names done.")
    print(firmName)
```

I'm attempting to pull a list of AIA Firms located in Florida. This is a snippet from a slightly larger piece of code, but it still has the problem I'm encountering. Normally I have the range set to cover all 24 pages of AIA Firms located in Florida, but for this example I have it set to just loop once and crawl the last page (page 24). Typically I have 'i' instead of '24' in the page variable.

When I run this code, I am getting the correct URL, but it is pulling information that seemingly doesn't exist on the page.

https://www.aia.org/firm-directory?filter%5Bcountry%5D=UNITED%20STATES&filter%5Bstate%5D=FL&page%5Bnumber%5D=24

This is the page I'm pulling from and this is the list of firm names I'm getting:

['Architect David P. Godwin', 'Architect ECW LLC', 'Architect Roseland, P.L.', 'Architect Stergas & Associates', 'Architectonic Inc', 'Architects Design Collaborative LLC', 'Architects Design Group Inc', 'Architects Design Group, Inc.', 'Architects Design Group, Inc.', 'Architects International Inc.', 'Architects Stergas & Associates', 'Architects Unlimited', 'Architects: Lewis + Whitlock, PA', 'Architectura Group', 'Architectural Partnership, Inc.', 'Architectural Studio, Inc.', 'Architecture Artistica Inc.', 'Architecture by Design', 'Architecture Joyce Owens', 'Architecture Joyce Owens LLC', 'ArchitectureWorks, LLC', 'Architeknics, Inc.', 'Arcticstar Design, Inc.', 'Arcwerks, Incorporated', 'ARK1TEK', 'Arkidesign, Inc.', 'Aron Temkin, Architect', 'Arquitectonica', 'Arquitectonica International', 'Art Castellanos, Architect', "Artisan's Architecture", 'Asbacher Architecture', 'Aspen Group', 'Atelier AEC, Inc.', 'ATELIER305, LLC', 'Atkins', 'Atkins North America Inc dba Faithful+Gould', 'Atlantic-AE, LLC', 'Atlas Safety & Security Design Inc.', 'Aude Smith Architecture', 'Austin Fox Architecture', 'AW Architects', 'B. Anderson Strait Architect', 'B1 Architects LLC', 'Bacon Group, Inc.', 'Baker Barrios Architects', 'Baker Barrios Architects', 'Banov Architects, PA', 'Barnett Fronczak Barlowe & Shuler Architects', 'Barr Architectural Studio, Inc.']

I've checked all over the page, but can't find these names anywhere. I also previously encountered a problem where my code suddenly seemed to not work after making no changes. The error was related to my page variable, so I believe it was unable to crawl the page. I'm guessing I'm not crawling the page I think I'm crawling, but I don't exactly understand how to check that.

I'm losing my mind here because I just ran it again as I was typing this but had it print the 'info' variable to see exactly what my program was pulling and it was the correct information. The code didn't change except for a 'print(info)' line and now it's pulling a completely different set of information—the right information, but unless I figure out why it's randomly pulling different things this is a useless learning project for myself.

I've tried pulling from specific pages rather than looping through all 24. I've tried checking the information I'm pulling. I've tried adding a 5 second delay between page crawls in case there was some sort of rate limit.

I guess at this point, I'm trying to figure out why my program seemingly pulls random information? Is it related to the site I'm trying to crawl? Is there some sort of limit that I'm hitting? Should I add a 10 second timer between each page crawl? Truly at a loss here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from where you get the data from, running the script in your question I get an exception.

The data you see on the page is loaded from external URL (via JavaScript). So to load the info about the companies you can simulate this request:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

api_url = 'https://api.aia.org/firm-directory'

params = {
    "filter[country]": "UNITED STATES",
    "filter[state]": "FL",
    "page[number]": "1",
    "page[size]": "50",
    "q": "",
    "sort[criteria]": "firm_name",
    "sort[order]": "asc",
}

all_data = []
for params["page[number]"] in range(1, 3):    # <-- increase number of pages here
    data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()
    all_data.extend(d['attributes'] for d in data['data'])

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                      firm_name                                  address_line_1 address_line_2                city state        country         zip                          firm_url
0                                            (allegedly) design                      3015 W Santiago St , Apt 2                              Tampa    FL  UNITED STATES  33629-8189           www.allegedlydesign.com
1                                                 2+ Architects                               260 Andalusia Ave                       Coral Gables    FL  UNITED STATES  33134-5902          www.2plus-architects.com
2                                          A BOHEME Design, LLC                   PO BOX 611328, 31 Main Street                     Rosemary Beach    FL  UNITED STATES  32461-1002             www.abohemedesign.com
3                                                 A Calist, LLC                                  6872 Caviro Ln                      Boynton Beach    FL  UNITED STATES  33437-3700                              None
4                                      A.T. Franco & Associates                                  500 Se 11Th Ct                    Fort Lauderdale    FL  UNITED STATES  33316-1146                  www.atfranco.com
5                                         AB Design Group, Inc.                       1441 N Ronald Reagan Blvd                           Longwood    FL  UNITED STATES  32750-3404             www.abdesigngroup.com
6                                         ACAI Associates, Inc.               2937 W Cypress Creek Rd , Ste 200                    Fort Lauderdale    FL  UNITED STATES  33309-1761                 www.acaiworld.com
7                                         Acme Architects, Inc.                                  3575 Linden Ln                              Miami    FL  UNITED STATES  33133-5614                       www.acme.ac


...and so on.
```